# Magento 2 get Block Toolbar custom module gives Error

Tags: blocks, magento2.2.2, toolbar

In `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="my-block-name" template="Vendor_Module::contents.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

In `content.phtml`

```
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $toolBarBlock \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
print_r(toolBarBlock->getTotalNum());
```

I get error:

```
"PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member 
 function getSize() on null in 
 .../htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php:609
```

Line 609:

```
/**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalNum()
    {
        return $this->getCollection()->getSize();
    }
```

Not sure what I am missing anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your toolbar has no collection, but it is required. In the original magento layout the Toolbar block rendered inside the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` block, which access toolbar from the layout and set the product collection:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php

```
/**
 * Need use as _prepareLayout - but problem in declaring collection from
 * another block (was problem with search result)
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

    $this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

    $collection->load();

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

I think you should declare\create own toolbar block and rewrite the `getCollection()` method, or set it manually before layout render.